# How to display from line 10 to line 23 in from passwd using tail?

Tags: tail

How to display from line 10 to line 23 in from passwd using tail?

I know that using `tail -1/etc/passwd` It will display last line from passwd

So please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the commands "head" and "tail" like so:

```
head -n23 filename | tail -n14
```

Comment: can I make using tail only ?

Answer (score 1):

Like [Squall5668](https://askubuntu.com/users/109404/squall5668) posted, you would have to use head and tail programs together. As an alternative, you may prefer to use sed as a single command, like this

```
sed -n '10,23p' filename
```